# How do I find the average time?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am currently working on this project and have some issues finding the average time based on their corresponding types. For now, I have my output as shown below after reading my CSV file.

```
#Following this format (x typeList : timeTakenList)

0 Lift : 5 days, 5:39:00
1 Lift : 5 days, 5:31:00
2 lighting : 3 days, 9:47:00
3 ACMV : 5 days, 5:21:00
4 lighting : 3 days, 9:32:00
.
.
.
```

How do I calculate the average time taken for each type such that I have the following output?

```
0 Lift : (5 days, 5:31:00 + 5 days, 5:39:00) / 2
1 lighting : (3 days, 9:47:00 + 3 days, 9:32:00) / 2
2 ACMV : 5 days, 5:21:00
.
.
.
```

The timeTakenList is calculated from subtracting another column, Acknowledged Date from the column CompletedDate.

```
timeTakenList = completedDate - acknowledgedDate
```

There is a ton of other types in the typeList and I'm trying to avoid doing an if statement like if typeList[x] == "Lift", then add the time together, etc.

Example of .csv file:

[image]

I'm not too sure how else to make my question clearer, but any help is much appreciated.

Comment: does typeList contains strings such as ["0 Lighting", "1 Lighting"...]

Comment: First part: Take the values from `timeTakenList` and convert them to hours.

Comment: @Harry nope, typeList is just the [Lighting, Lighting, Air-Con, ...] The number before that is just for easier reference to my .csv file.

Comment: Please give an example for your CSV file in its original format.

Comment: @MartinEvans I have included a part of the .csv file for reference. Hopefully it's what you meant.

Comment: Actually the raw file is more useful than a screenshot as it will show the format of the file better. i.e. is it using TABs, commas, semicolons? All are quite common. The raw data also allows people to copy/paste the data rather than having to type it in.

Answer (score 0):

check the below implementation.

```
import re

typeList = ["Lighting", "Lighting", "Air-Con", "Air-Con", "Toilet"]

timeTakenList = ["10hours", "5hours", "2days, 5hrs", "5hours", "4hours"]

def convertTime(total_time):
    li = list(map(int,re.sub(r"days|hrs|hours","",total_time).split(",")))
    if len(li) == 2:
        return li[0] * 24 + li[1]
        return li[0]

def convertDays(total_time):
    days = int(total_time / 24)
    hours = total_time % 24
    if (hours).is_integer():
        hours = int(hours)
    if days == 0:
        return str(hours) + "hours"
    return str(days) + "days, " + str(hours) + "hrs"

def avg(numbers):
    av = float(sum(numbers)) / max(len(numbers), 1)
return av 

avgTime = {}

for i, types in enumerate(typeList):
    if avgTime.has_key(types):
        avgTime[types].append(convertTime(timeTakenList[i]))
    else:
        avgTime[types] = [convertTime(timeTakenList[i])]

for types in avgTime.keys():
    print types + " : " + convertDays(avg(avgTime[types]))
```

**Algo**

- Convert strip "hours", "hrs", "days" from the timeTakenList list.
- convert the elements consisting of days and hours into hours for
  easier avg calculation
- create hash having typeList elements as keys and converted
  timeTakenList elements as list of values
- print the values for each key converted back to days and hours.

Comment: Just dropping code without any explanation ist not very helpful for future readers.